# I am working on a simple C program to check temperature and give feedback to user. I am lost on how to limit character inputs like a,b,c

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

Problem
Develop a C program that checks temperature. The program should accept numbers only. If users enter letters,the program should say, wrong input. Note that temperature should be between 1-35. Any number outside this results in "out of range".

Here is my code. Users who input letters of alphabet should be told "wrong input"

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int temp;

    printf("Enter a Temperature between 1-35: ");
    scanf("%d",&temp);

    if(temp < 1)
    {
      printf("Input out of range");
    }
    else if(temp <= 12)
    {
        printf("Too cold");
    }
    else if(temp <= 19)
    {
        printf("Moderately cold");
    }
    else if(temp <= 25)
    {
        printf("Normal Temperature");
    }
    else if(temp <= 30)
    {
        printf("Hot");
    }
    else if(temp <= 35)
    {
        printf("Too Hot");
    }
    else if(temp > 35)
    {
        printf("Input out of range");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Wrong Input");
    }

   return 0;
}
```

I have tried declaring temp as char in vain.

Answer (score 1):

**From the man page**

**DESCRIPTION:**

The scanf() family of functions scans input according to format as described below. This format may contain conversion specifications; the results from such conversions, if any, are stored in the locations pointed to by the pointer arguments that follow format.  Each pointer argument must be of a type that is appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding  conversion specification.

**RETURN VALUE:**

On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

As per this, you should check the return value of scanf.

```
if (scanf ("%d%, &temp) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid input.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It will take care of characters, but if you enter a floating point variable, it will truncate the number — discard the mantissa — and accept the whole part as a valid number. If you enter an integer followed by some junk, scanf reads the input till it find the first non-integer — leaving the rest of the input in the input buffer(which itself lead to 10 other problems) — and accepts the number. There are many other issues with scanf, you'll find plenty of questions pertaining to them on stackoverflow.

**OT:**

Suggest using the double data type.
Suggest looking into fgets and strtol/strtod family of functions. Suggest reading the man page of the functions during coding.

See also: http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html